# ask_vault_pass = true in ansible.cfg breaks ansible-lint

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault, ansible-lint

In my ansible playbook repository I have a few vault-encrypted group variable files, and an ansible.cfg with the following contents:

```
[defaults]
ask_vault_pass = true
```

This appears to break ansible lint:

```
[Mon Mar 11 12:43 PM] sam @ REDACTED:~/dev/redacted $ ansible-lint
Vault password: Vault password: Vault password: Vault password: Vault password:
```

I do not want to supply the vault password to `ansible-lint`. If I take `ask_vault_pass` out of `ansible.cfg`, `ansible-lint` works as anticipated. However, pretty much ever play we run requires the vault password so setting `ask_vault_pass=true` is greatly desired.

Is there a way to get `ansible-lint` to ignore settings in `ansible.cfg`? Or even better, set `ask_vault_pass = false` explicitly for `ansible-lint`?

I am using:

```
ansible                   9.3.0
ansible-compat            4.1.11
ansible-core              2.16.4
ansible-lint              24.2.0
```

Comment: The `ansible-lint` package for your editor should be working around this limitation. If this is for CI, then normally an `ansible.cfg` would not be part of the code retrieval for the pipeline. What is the use case causing this conflict if not one of those two?

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard We run ansible-lint directly while developing playbooks, and as a pre-commit hook on our ansible playbook repository (through the pre-commit integration https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/blob/main/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml). We see the above breakage in both cases. We also run playbooks directly from our development machines, not only from CI.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard I wouldn't agree on "normally an `ansible.cfg` would not be part of the code retrieval for the pipeline". Having the same configuration for CI and production makes perfect sense and allows to properly test the playbooks. Besides, `ansible-lint` extension, for example, for IntelliJ IDEA, is extremely slow and conflicts with other extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your problem with the versions of the packages you've listed. Probably, there are some other factors such as Python version or OS.

From `ansible-lint` [documentation](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/usage/?h=vault#vaults):

> As ansible-lint executes ansible, it also needs access to encrypted secrets. If you do not give access to them or you are concerned about security implications, you should consider refactoring your code to allow it to be linted without access to real secrets:
>
> - Configure dummy fallback values that are used during linting, so Ansible will not complain about undefined variables.
> - Exclude the problematic files from the linting process.
>
> ...
>
> Internally ansible-lint runs ansible-playbook --syntax-check on each playbook and also on roles.
> ...

That means, that `ansible` checks `ansible.cfg` and asks the vault password, not `ansible-lint`.

This leads us the fact that [the configuration settings set via the environment variables have higher priority than the ones set via `ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file). So, you can simply use [`ANSIBLE_ASK_VAULT_PASS`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-ask-vault-pass):

```
ANSIBLE_ASK_VAULT_PASS=false ansible-lint
```

Comment: Perhaps you are unable to reproduce due to there not being any vault-encrypted files in your test environment? I will add a note to the issue. Either way, your workaround works and I was able to add the environment variable to the pre commit hook as well: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/758#issuecomment-404554291

Comment: @SamCoulter I've tried with an encrypted secret in the playbook, in a vars file loaded with `vars_files`, and with an encrypted inventory passed via `ANSIBLE_INVENTORY` (doesn't really matter but still) - and it worked. Your GitHub issue has been closed, btw...